# Added new target: Could not load NIB in bundle (NSInternalInconsistencyException)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nib

I'm attempting to add a new build target in Xcode, and so far everything has been going fine - or I've at least been able to figure out why stuff was breaking/not compiling.

Now however, I'm stuck. When building and starting the app using the new target, the app fails with this:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'Valider1''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f71be83 0x39a7c6c7 0x2f71bdc5 0x321ff391 0x321610fb 0x31fc2b59 0x31ea479d 0x31f4f895 0x31f4f7ab 0x31f4ed89 0x31f4eab1 0x31f4e821 0x31f4e7b9 0x31ea0353 0x31b26943 0x31b22167 0x31b21ff9 0x31b21a0d 0x31b2181f 0x31f1fa3b 0x31f0aedf 0x31ea5a07 0x31ea4cfd 0x31f0a321 0x3438476d 0x34384357 0x2f6e6777 0x2f6e6713 0x2f6e4edf 0x2f64f471 0x2f64f253 0x31f095c3 0x31f04845 0xcd059 0x39f75ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Now, I've searched for 2 hours regarding this, and theres a lot of results with suggestions, but none of them has solved the problem in my case.

The original build target works perfectly, and I'm using the same app delegate file for both targets.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Tried simulator/real device
- Double checked that the "Valider1" is in "Compile sources"
- Double checked that "Copy bundle resources" contains my "MainWindow.xib" (this is the nib used for "Valider1"
- Double checked that "Valider1" is written correctly everywhere
- Cleaned project 100 times
- Validated that the Valider.m and "MainWindow.xib" has the new target checked in target membership
- .plist files, build settings etc. is all identical to the original and working target

Please SO, tell me what I've done wrong or missed!

edit:
I call my nib like this:

```
Valider1 *validerVC = [[Valider1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Valider1" bundle:nil mode:ny_mode];

validerVC.delegate = self;
```

and it works perfectly when using the original target.

EDIT 2:
I tried with another nib from my project, but still same error.
It would appear that the nibs are not being copied to the new target app, but I have no idea why :/

Comment: Make sure you are adding resources to new target as well. Select target and from build phases under resources tab, see if some resources are missing, if missing add them.

Comment: He Wants a Valider1.xib - not a MainWindow.xib or Valider.m

Comment: C_X: This I've double checked as well :)
Daij-Djan: Not sure what you mean about "he wants". If by "he" you mean "Xcode", then I don't think so, because the original target works perfectly with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove and re-add the .xib file to Copy Bundle Resources**

1. Go to your project settings.
2. Select your target.
3. Click on Build Phases.
4. Scroll down to Copy Bundle Resources and expand that section.
5. Check if your .xib file is present in this list -> then remove it.
6. Now re-add your .xib file by clicking the plus-button and find the file.

It helped me, I hope it helps you as well!